# Jetpack compose Grid with adaptive numbers of columns based on size

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a grid of text items, witch can vary in size, and I would like for as many items to fix in one row as the size allows.

This is what I got so far
For example in this case, Ias you see the first row has space for additional items, while climbing should be Climbing and mountaineering
[image]

I have been trying to use LazyVerticalGrid, is there any way to automatically calculate span based on item size?

`

```
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Adaptive(120.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(14.dp)){
    items(selected.size){i->
        ItemHobbySelected(text = selected[i])
    }
}


@Composable
fun ItemHobbySelected(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit={}){
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentWidth()
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .background(Color.White)) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .padding(16.dp, 8.dp, 16.dp, 8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .clickable(onClick = onClick),
            text = text,maxLines =1,
            color = Color(0xFF3D3D3D)
        )
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such designs you can use [Google Accompanist's](https://github.com/google/accompanist) [FlowLayout](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/flowlayout). Add the version based on the Compose version you are using.

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:<version>"
```

It has two Composables. `FlowRow` and `FlowColumn`. You need FlowRow:

```
FlowRow(
   mainAxisSpacing = 10.dp,
   crossAxisSpacing = 10.dp,
   modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxWidth()
       .padding(4.dp),
   mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center
   ) {
      selected.forEach{ item ->
          ItemHobbySelected(text = "//Whatever you want")
}
```

You can modify the spacings to get your desired layout.