# How to set dynamic height on LazyVerticalGrid inside Column verticalscroll?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My goal is to do something like this:

[image]

Currently I make my code like this:

```
Column(vertical scroll) {
Image()
Text()
LazyVerticalGrid(
modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)
)
Text()
LazyRow()
}
```

How can I set the height according to the length of the items contained in it, because currently, if the items exceed 200.dp it will be truncated.

What's the best solution?

---

do I have to change it to LazyVertivalGrid as the parent, but how do I set the padding for each item in the future?

Comment: Why are you setting 200.dp height? Can't you just set fillMaxWidth and the height will be dynamic?

Comment: I'm using height, because if we don't give it a constraint it will cause this error : 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.' @Hamed

Comment: Why do you need a scrollable column?

Comment: There's a workaround for this error. It's not perfect but it works. Instead of LazyVerticalGrid you can use Google's accompanist flowRow. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74593277/8357673 @JulsapargiNursam

Comment: Thanks you @Hamed

For now I make LazyGrid the parent and the others I include as items

Comment: Can you please post solution if you were able to do it? I am also facing the same problem.